# OpenCV find sub images

Tags: opencv, image-recognition

I have a scanner which is big enough to scan multiple pictures at once.
Unfortunatelly, all the pictures are stored in one jpg file, separated only by 
white borders. Is there any way to automatically find the sub images and store them
in separate files? I was thinking about using OpenCV to get the job done, but
I can't find the right functions. Does anybody know which OpenCV function would work, or if there is any other approach (using linux)?

Thanks,
Konstantin

Comment: What kinds of assumptions can you make?  Are all the pictures rectangles?  Do they always appear in the same locations?  The simplest case is probably having perfect rectangles which always appear somewhere inside a defined grid, one rectangle per grid element.  Assuming that no rectangles are crooked would be great too.  Is any error acceptable?  If so should it leave extra whitespace or take away some of the picture?

Comment: The pictures are more or less rotated rectangles of different sizes, they don't always appear in the same location, it would be acceptable to loose some percentage of the image's border pixels so that it becomes a perfect rectangle. The background is not perfectly white, but distinguishable from the images themselves.

Comment: I have not done this before so take it with a grain of salt but it sounds like you want to use contour finding.  First it would be ideal if you could threshold the image to make the images all black and the background all white.  Depending on how well that works you may need to blur it as well.  Then you could find the contours and give them bounding boxes.  OpenCV can do all of that, see tutorials [here](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/table_of_content_imgproc/table_of_content_imgproc.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My quick and dirty solution that worked with my images looks like this. I hope people with similar problem can use this as a starting point on how to use OpenCV.

```
// g++ `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` parse.cp

// include standard OpenCV headers, same as before
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// all the new API is put into "cv" namespace. Export its content
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    string imagename = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "lena.jpg";

    // the newer cvLoadImage alternative with MATLAB-style name
    Mat imgf = imread("original/"+imagename);

    if( !imgf.data ) // check if the image has been loaded properly
        return -1;

    int border = 1000;
    Mat img(imgf.rows+2*border,imgf.cols+2*border,CV_8UC3,Scalar(255,255,255));
    for (int i=0; i<imgf.cols; ++i) {
        for (int j=0; j<imgf.rows; ++j) {
            img.at<Vec3b>(j+border,i+border) = imgf.at<Vec3b>(j,i);
        }
    }

    cout << "created border\n";
    Mat mask;
    img.copyTo(mask);

    Scalar diff(2,2,2);
    floodFill(mask, Point(0,0), Scalar(0,0,255), NULL, diff, diff);

    cout << "flood filled\n";

    imwrite("flood.png",mask);

    for (int i=0; i<mask.cols; ++i) {
        for (int j=0; j<mask.rows; ++j) {
            if(mask.at<Vec3b>(j,i) != Vec3b(0,0,255)) {
                mask.at<Vec3b>(j,i) = Vec3b(0,0,0);
            } else {
                mask.at<Vec3b>(j,i) = Vec3b(255,255,255);
            }
        }
    }

    cvtColor( mask, mask, CV_RGB2GRAY );

    cout << "mask created\n";

    imwrite("binary.png",mask);

    Mat sobelX;
    Mat sobelY;
    Mat sobel;
    Sobel(mask,sobelX,CV_16S,1,0);
    Sobel(mask,sobelY,CV_16S,0,1);
    sobel = abs(sobelX)+abs(sobelY);

    for (int i=0; i<mask.cols; ++i) {
        for (int j=0; j<mask.rows; ++j) {
            mask.at<char>(j,i) = abs(sobelX.at<short>(j,i))+abs(sobelY.at<short>(j,i));
        }
    }

    threshold(mask, mask, 127, 255, THRESH_BINARY);

    cout << "sobel done\n";

    imwrite("sobel.png",mask);

    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    findContours(mask, contours, hierarchy,
        CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );

    imwrite("contours.png",mask);

    cout << "contours done\n";

    // iterate through all the top-level contours
    int idx = 0;
    for( ; idx >= 0; idx = hierarchy[idx][0] )
    {
        RotatedRect box = minAreaRect(contours[idx]);
        if(box.size.width > 100 && box.size.height > 100) {
            Mat rot = getRotationMatrix2D(box.center,box.angle,1.0);
            Mat rotimg;
            warpAffine(img,rotimg,rot,Size(img.cols,img.rows));

            imwrite("rotimg.png",rotimg);
            Mat subimg(box.size.width,box.size.height,CV_8UC3);
            getRectSubPix(rotimg,box.size,box.center,subimg);

            stringstream name;
            name << "subimg_"<< imagename << "_" << idx << ".png";
            cout << name.str() << "\n"; 
            imwrite(name.str(),subimg);
        }
    }

    imwrite("img.png",img);
    imwrite("mask.png",mask);

    cout << "Done\n";

    return 0;
}
```